# How to check words with the same characters where the words in one variable

Tags: go

I'm thinking up about how I find the same characters in one variable looks like this:

```
var words string = "abab"
```

and then I want's to eliminate the same characters in that one variable and here's the output to be

Output:

```
ab
```

have any solution about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be the use of go `map[]` to track the taken characters.

sample code:

```golang
func main() {
    s := "abcdaabcefgahccij"
    newS := ""
    taken := make(map[rune]int)
    for _, value := range s {
        if _, ok := taken[value]; !ok {
            taken[value] = 1
            newS += string(value)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(newS)
}
```

Output:

```
abcdefghij
```